# Spring MVC + Hibernate - Update some attributes from form

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="admins", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="editar")
public String editarAdmin(@ModelAttribute("cadastroform") Usuario usuario){
    usuarioService.atualizaUsuario(usuario); //do the update
    return "redirect:/admin/admins?listar";
}
```

As you can see, I'm receiving the Usuario object and updating it, but, for that, I need to have this form on my jsp:

```
<sf:form id="formCadastrarAdmin" method="post" modelAttribute="cadastroform">
<label for="tfNome">Nome*: </label>
<sf:input path="nome" type="text" id="tfNome" name="nome" placeholder="Digite o nome do novo administrador"/>
<label for="tfEmail">E-mail*: </label>
<sf:input path="email" type="text" id="tfEmail" name="email" placeholder="Digite o email do novo administrador"/>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${!empty param.editar}">
        <sf:input path="login" type="hidden" id="tfLogin" name="login" placeholder="Digite o login do novo administrador"/>
        <sf:input path="senha" type="hidden" name="senha" placeholder="Digitar senha de acesso"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <label for="tfLogin">Login*:  </label>
        <sf:input path="login" type="text" id="tfLogin" name="login" placeholder="Digite o login do novo administrador"/>
        <label for="tfSenha">Senha*: </label>
        <sf:input path="senha" type="password" id="tfSenha" name="senha" placeholder="Digitar senha de acesso"/>
        <label for="tfSenhaRepeat">Confirmação de senha*: </label>
        <input type="password" id="tfSenhaRepeat" name="senhaRepeat" placeholder="Redigitar senha de acesso"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<label for="sfTipo">Autoridades*: </label>

<div id="autoridades">
    <sf:checkboxes items="${listaAutoridades}" delimiter="</br>" path="authorities" cssClass="box_autoridade"
                   itemValue="authority" itemLabel="descricao"></sf:checkboxes>
</div>

<sf:input type="hidden" path="foto" value="default"/>  
<sf:input type="hidden" path="tipo" value="default"/>  
<sf:input type="hidden" path="id"/>
<sf:input type="hidden" path="dataCadastro"/>

<br/>
<button type="submit" id="btEnviar" onclick="return false">Cadastrar</button>
<button type="reset" id="btLimpar">Limpar</button>
```

So, I'm having a lot of hidden fields, in order to fill all the attributes of the Usuario object that I don't want to change. I could just omit all these hidden fields and retrieve the object from database in my controller, but I think it wouldn't be correct.

My question is: is the hidden field approach correct? If it's not, what's the most recommended way to update an object from a form?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly when I have a form that doesn't exactly matches the persisted object I end up creating a new class which will represent that particular piece of data. You could also refactor your domain object into several classes which will individually match a form. The major benefit from this approach is that can easily validate each instance which would be difficult if you expect the full, in this case, `User` object with partial data when submitting the form.

*This example is just for illustration. In general it's better to create separate tables/entities instead of one big table/entity.*

```
@Entity
class User extends UserDetails {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}


@MappedSuperclass
class User extends UserDetails {
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String username;
    private String password;
}


@MappedSuperclass
class UserProfile {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    @Email
    private String email;
}
```

Comment: In this case, in my controller, I will have to retrieve my object from database, set the fields with the form class attributes and update the object, right?

Answer (score 2):

I think, the best approach depends on what you need from your application. Security? - sending unnecessary data to the client may be a bad idea. Scalability? - your approach probably is the most scalable. Performance? - you may consider storing your `usuario` object in a session attribute between controller invocations instead of retrieving its data from the DB.

If you decide to store the `Usuario` form backing object as a session attribute between controller invocations, Spring MVC has the `@SessionAttribute` annotation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8645619/2842067) is an example of its usage.